# How can I get wget to always download the file, e.g. I don't want "The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do"

Tags: linux, download, wget

I'm giving a very simple command, such as

```
wget http://www.example.com/updates/Avail.asp -O avail
```

Which downloads a very small file containing just a few integers indicating which updates to my app's database are available. My app then looks at the contents of the file to see if any further action is required.

But I keep getting

```
The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

As near as I can tell, wget is determining that the file exists and is the same size as the one at the remote server, and so skips the transfer. It seems to be ignoring all timestamps.

The problem is, the file probably *has* changed, but the size remained the same. How can I get wget to download it again?

I *have* considered doing this:

```
wget -v http://www.jepptech.com/tfr/Available.asp?UserID=Public -O - > avail
```

But I'm worried that this will wipe out **avail** if the transfer fails.

Meta: what are the criteria that wget uses to decide a file has been downloaded? Is it just the file size, as I suspect?

---

Answering some of the comments:

re: worrying about wiping out avail if the transfer fails -- I'm thinking of the case where the network is down, the remote server doesn't answer, or any number of other cases where the download wouldn't even get started. I'm hoping that in those cases, wget would just leave the file alone.

I did try `wget -N ...` and it didn't help. I also received this message: `WARNING: timestamping does nothing in combination with -O. See the manual for details.`

The `--no-cache` option also did not help. My understanding is that this is a pragma to remote servers telling them not to cache the file. I don't think it tells wget that the local copy should be disregarded.

I considered the possibility that wget was comparing a hash, but I examined the headers coming from the remote server and there's no hash in them. I also tried modifying my local copy slightly to change its hash and it didn't help. I'll wait until I'm sure the file has changed on the server and try again. (Update: the file has changed on the server but wget did not pick it up.)

Re: "Possible duplicate of How to force redownload with wget?", that solution was to use `-O - > avail`, which I already thought of, but see my previous comments about not wanting to wipe out avail.

Re: "Relevant: How to allow wget to overwrite files" -- yes, I already found that solution. It solves a different problem, but not this one. Although one of the non-accepted answers was to use `curl` instead, and I think I'm going to go with that route.

Thanks for everybody's input.

Comment: For now, I'm switching to curl, but I am curious as to whether this can be done with wget.

Comment: "But I'm worried that this will wipe out avail if the transfer fails." > If it's overwriting the file, what would you *want* it to do when the transfer fails? If you're overwriting the file and stop mid-file, there's no way to guarantee that the file isn't corrupt.

Comment: did you try: wget -N http://www.example.com/updates/Avail.asp -O avail

Comment: I'm not sure this problem is easily reproduceable, but what about throwing "--no-cache" as an option to prevent caching ?

Comment: You said "*The problem is, the file **probably** has changed*" but have you actually tested this, when the file **really has changed** but is still the same size? Maybe wget is smarter than you think, could be comparing  a hash or similar

Comment: Relevant: [How to allow wget to overwrite files](http://serverfault.com/a/171373)

Comment: Relevant: [How to force wget to overwrite an existing file ignoring timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30418188)

Comment: I give up. I'm convinced that the answers are "it can't be done" and "use curl instead". I'm just going to use curl.